# Downloading files from Sharepoint server using c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, c#-3.0

I am new to sharepoint and i dont have enough knowledge about it. 
I wants to make a web application using c#. This application will be downloading the files from sharepoint server which is having some files on it. 
Can anybody help me in this if this is possible? >>

Thanks in Advance

Chetz

Answer (score 0):

When do the files need to be downloaded?
If once a day, i would suggest to use a timerjob (a scheduled event in sharepoint).
Else, you need to create a Filesystemwatcher (service) that checks a folder if a new file is added and than add it to sharepoint.

To create a webapplication, I suggest to user a "farm feature". When activating this feature, a webapplication can be created.